# WFFM Send Email save action issue

Tags: wffm

We are using WFFM "Send Email Message" save action to send mails after submitting the form.The mails are being sent successfully to some domains but it fails to send to few domains.

Also sending the mails is not consistent sometimes the mails are sent and sometime it is failing for the same domain.

We are using Sitecore 8.2 update 3 and WFFM 8.2 update 4.

Not understanding whether this issue with WFFM save action or some thing to do with Mail server.

Comment: are there any errors in the log file?  My first guess is it's your mail server.  I had similar problems, our mail server would get overloaded so we ended up using message queuing (Microsoft Message Queue) to address the problem.

Comment: Knowing what I know about email in general, if the Save Action will send emails to some addresses, but not others, the issue is not with WFFM Save Action, and instead has to deal with either SMTP spam filters, deliverability, DKIM/SPF, etc. All of that means that you should be troubleshooting the deliverability past Sitecore.

Comment: No error in logs. As suggested, will troubleshoot the deliverability past sitecore